# Pillow installation PyPy3 missing zlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library, pypy

I'm curretnly trying to use PIL with PyPy3, but no matter how I try to install it I get an error. First I tried to install it normally using `pypy3 pip install pillow`, but got the error that I need zlib. So after searching for a solution for a while I found the `easy_install pillow` command which fixed this problem for most people, but for me it leads to the same error. I hope somebody can help me out.

**Error:**

```
File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-uqrsyszz\Pillow-4.0.0\setup.py", line 791, in <module> setuptools.sandbox.UnpickleableException: RequiredDependencyException('\n\nThe headers or library files could not be found for zlib,\na required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.\n\nPlease see the install instructions at:\n   http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html\n\n')
```

Comment: Could you post the error that you got?

Comment: @Anwarvic oh yes, sure:
```File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-uqrsyszz\Pillow-4.0.0\setup.py", line 791, in <module>
setuptools.sandbox.UnpickleableException: RequiredDependencyException('\n\nThe headers or library files could not be found for zlib,\na required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.\n\nPlease see the install instructions at:\n   http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html\n\n')```

Comment: OK, I've just reproduced your error... apparently, you're installing an older version of pillow (`4.0.0` according to the posted error). So, I think you should try to install a newer version... try out this `pip install pillow==7.2.0`

Comment: Thanks for your help, I just tried it but I get the error ```The headers or library files could not be found for zlib,
    a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.```

Answer (score 4):

got it fixed by using `pypy3 install pillow --global-option="build_ext" --global-option="--disable-zlib" --global-option="--disable-jpeg"`. :)

Comment: Strange: pip should be able to find the binary wheel at the bottom of this page https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/#files so you should not have to compile from source. What does your pypy show for `sys.version`?

Answer (score 2):

I was having a similar issue.
After some research, I found [this solution](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/4242#issuecomment-635490750) which got me most of the way there.  I had to perform step #4 below in addition to get it to work for me:

1. Install homebrew (if you don't already have it):
   `/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"`
2. Brew install zlib:

`brew install zlib`

3. Set the following variables:

`export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/zlib/lib"`

`export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/zlib/include"`

4. Brew install jpeg

`brew install jpeg`

5. Finally, pip install Pillow:

`pip3 install Pillow==7.1.2`

Comment: For older Pillow versions I needed to add: `CFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/zlib/include"`

Comment: My homebrew used a different folder. I needed `export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/zlib/lib"` and `export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/zlib/include"`. The relevant folder can be found using `brew --prefix zlib`

Answer (score 1):

For linux debian based systems, the below solves the issue.

```
sudo apt install libjpeg-dev zlib1g zlib1g-dev
```

Comment: The question clearly show a Windows system according to the file management system shown. Linux, Debian, whatever other OS are out of topic.

Comment: @AvyWam Yes, but when I search this error for linux, the search engine directs me to this page.

Comment: Well, the answer helped me. I am using python via WSL2 (Ubuntu).